# java: initialization of static fields of the same class during class initialization

Tags: java

It looks like deadlock happened during starting the application. 
I have jstack file in which i found that one thread call TariffModelManager.<clinit> method and there are others multiple threads calling TariffModelManager.getInstance() method.
The code of TariffModelManager following:

```
public class TariffModelManager{
    ...
    private static final TariffModelManager tariffModelManager = TariffModelManager.getInstance();
    ...
    private static volatile TariffModelManager _instance;

    private TariffModelManager(){}

    public static TariffModelManager getInstance() {
        if(_instance == null) {
            synchronized(TariffModelManager.class) {
                if(_instance == null) _instance = new TariffModelManager();
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }
    ... 
}
```

I think, this is an apparent mistake to initialize static field by calling getInstance() method in which checked another field (_instance), that described bellow in the code, but what is really happened?

1. During class initialization, static fields are initialized from up to down;
2. we trying to init "tariffModelManager" field...
3. calling method getInstance(), that checks _instance field (but it is not initialized!);
4. then we must execute constructor of this class;
5. if _instance field has been initialized in constructor, can it be set to null in static fields initialization sequence?

**My question is not how to solve this, but describe what is really happened when this code executed!**

**UPDATE:**
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) i found detailed class initialization procedure, but it is still not clear, in which order "tariffModelManager" and "_instance" fields are initialized.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work for me. When I add a main method that prints the `TariffModelManager.getInstance()`, it does just that.

Comment: yes, i tested it too, but not in concurrent environment. As I said above, there was a problem with application that uses this code in concurrent environment and i think this is the cause.

Comment: 1. Nobody can call the `getInstance()` method until the class is intialized, and there is a synchronization barrier against multiple concurrent initializations. 2. Static fields are intialized first to last, as you said yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify what's happening by putting field breakpoints on the two static fields.

I've modified your sample a bit:

```
class TariffModelManager {
    private static final TariffModelManager tariffModelManager = TariffModelManager.getInstance();
    private static volatile TariffModelManager _instance = new TariffModelManager();

    private TariffModelManager() {
        System.out.println("From Constructor: " + this);
    }

    public static TariffModelManager getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            synchronized (TariffModelManager.class) {
                if (_instance == null) {
                    _instance = new TariffModelManager();
                    System.out.println("Creating new instance: " + _instance);
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TariffModelManager.getInstance();

        System.out.println("tariffModelManager: " + TariffModelManager.tariffModelManager);
        System.out.println("_instance: " + TariffModelManager._instance);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
From Constructor: TariffModelManager@ea4a92b
Creating new instance: TariffModelManager@ea4a92b
From Constructor: TariffModelManager@3c5a99da
tariffModelManager: TariffModelManager@ea4a92b
_instance: TariffModelManager@3c5a99da
```

The static field `tariffModelManager` is initialized first. When the `getInstance` method is called `_instance` is null - i.e. the default value and not initialized yet. Then it is initialized inside that method and the value is assigned to `tariffModelManager` as well. Then it is reinitialized again according to the static initialization order: [Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

This is funny, because

```
class TariffModelManager {
    private static final TariffModelManager tariffModelManager = _instance;
    private static volatile TariffModelManager _instance = new TariffModelManager();

    private TariffModelManager() {
        System.out.println("From Constructor: " + this);
    }

    public static TariffModelManager getInstance() {
       return _instance;
    }
}
```

is invalid java, but the static methods gives you a way to "work around" it (well tariffModelManager will be null, not really what's intended, but still compiles):

```
class TariffModelManager {
    private static final TariffModelManager tariffModelManager = getInstance();
    private static volatile TariffModelManager _instance = new TariffModelManager();

    private TariffModelManager() {
        System.out.println("From Constructor: " + this);
    }

    public static TariffModelManager getInstance() {
       return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tested this also. It is interesting, but when i explicitly set _instance to null, two different instance are created. But if I do not assigned it explicitly, i.e. leave just: `private static volatile TariffModelManager _instance;` then  "tariffModelManager" and "_instance" fields are the same!